# c# Write data to an rtf file

Tags: c#

I am trying to write data to an RTF file and set certain characters to a different color. I found out how to do it in a box but I can't figure out how to write it to a file.

Answer (score 1):

If by "do it on a box" you mean `RichTextBox` you can use the `RichTextBox.SaveFile()` mothod.
Take a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextboxstreamtype.aspx).

Comment: How would I write it to a file.

Comment: what do you understand from 'SaveFile'. If you can put colored text in RTB then when you save it the info goes with it and next time when you open it in Word or other RichText capable app it will show.